# image overlay in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, image, overlay

Can anyone please help with how to overlay an image i.e NEW/SOLD icon over my properties listings on the homepage featured property: www.integratedproperty.co.uk

Also need the same on the available properties and again on the detailed property page. At the moment I've got a lot of in consistencies.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Use an image with position absolute

Comment: I think the image overlay is a little bit limiting due to the theme and certain restrictions. I think I'll have to have the image overlay directly on the image instead of a separate graphic